# ExtendedFloatingActionButton - Icon gravity set to text End but icon not center when it's shrieked

Tags: android, floating-action-button, material-components, material-components-android

I am using com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02

When adding icon and setting its gravity to text end its not center.
[icon is a vector imported from resource manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZg3N.jpg).

Also when FAB is extended there is extra padding on the right side of the icon 
[yellow line shows the extra padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgJLB.jpg).

**XML Code**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dim_65dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/extended_floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim_8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim_8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/next"
        android:text="@string/get_started"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_white_24dp"
        app:iconTint="#000000"
        app:iconGravity="textEnd"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It works fine when no gravity is set but the arrow icon shows up on the left side of the FAB and text at right.[No extra padding too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UezGn.jpg)

Comment: Tried with `app:iconPadding="0dp"` if it removes the right padding from the icon?
Regarding the icon not centering when button is shrinked, maybe here you can find some information about it: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/671

Comment: Yes, adding `app:iconPadding="0dp"` removes extra right padding.